# Error submitting form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I developed a form in this [site](http://agenciafront.com.br/aldeia/evento) in php and javascript has a multiple select where the user will be able to select more than one value when sending my form it arrives with all the information but where there is multiple select it does not appear anything this and the line where it goes Have the array

```
<select id="select-picker" class="selectpicker config" multiple
         name="config[]" id="config[]" data-selected-text-format="count > 3" 
         title="Configurações do evento"> 



<select id="select-picker" class="selectpicker" multiple
         data-selected-text-format="count > 3" title="Selecione os equipamentos"
         name="equip[]" id="equip[]" required>
```

The question here is that I do not know how to call those tags `name = "config []"` or `name = "equip []"` for example in my php or javascript code could anyone help me follow the project codes:

HTML:

```
   <form class="form-budget" id="form-elements" onSubmit="return false">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 center">
                                        <div id="result"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Digite seu nome" name="name" id="name" required/>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Digite seu Email" name="email" id="email" required/>
                                    <input type="tel" placeholder="Digite seu Telefone" name="phone" id="phone" class="phone_with_ddd" required/>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Data do evento" name="date" id="date" class="date" required/>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <select id="select-picker" class="selectpicker config" multiple
                                            name="config[]" id="config[]"
                                            data-selected-text-format="count > 3" title="Configurações do evento">
                                        <option value="Mesas-Cadeiras" selected>Mesas e cadeiras</option>
                                        <option value="Auditório" selected>Auditório</option>
                                        <option value="Lounge">Lounge</option>
                                        <option value="Galeria">Galeria</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Quantidade de pessoas" name="quant" id="quant" class="quant" required/>

                                    <select id="select-picker" class="selectpicker" multiple
                                            data-selected-text-format="count > 3" title="Selecione os equipamentos"
                                            name="equip[]" id="equip[]" required>
                                        <option value="Projetor">Projetor</option>
                                        <option value="Som">Caixa de som</option>
                                        <option value="Flip-Chart">Flip-Chart</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit_btn">Enviar orçamento</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

JS:

```
$("#submit_btn").click(function() {
    //get input field values
    var user_name       = $('input[name=name]').val();
    var user_email      = $('input[name=email]').val();
    var user_phone      = $('input[name=phone]').val();
    var user_date       = $('input[name=date]').val();
    var user_config     = $('select[name=config] option:selected ').val(); 
    //console.log(user_config);
    var user_quant      = $('input[name=quant]').val();
    var user_equip      = $('select[name=equip] option:selected').val();
    //var user_message    = $('textarea[name=message]').val();

    //simple validation at client's end
    var post_data, output;
    var proceed = true;
    if(user_name==""){
        proceed = false;
    }
    if(user_email==""){
        proceed = false;
    }
    if(user_phone=="") {
        proceed = false;
    }

    if(user_quant=="") {
        proceed = false;
    }
    if(user_date=="") {
        proceed = false;
    }

    //everything looks good! proceed...
    if(proceed)
    {
        //data to be sent to server
        post_data = {'userName':user_name, 'userEmail':user_email, 'userPhone':user_phone, 'userDate':user_date, 'userConfig':user_config, 'userQuant':user_quant, 'userEquip':user_equip};

        //Ajax post data to server
        $.post('contact.php', post_data, function(response){

            //load json data from server and output message
            if(response.type == 'error')
            {
                output = '<div class="alert-danger" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:25px;">'+response.text+'</div>';
            }else{
                output = '<div class="alert-success" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:25px;">'+response.text+'</div>';

                //reset values in all input fields
                $('#form-elements input').val('');
                $('#form-elements textarea').val('');
            }

            $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();
        }, 'json');

    }
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to_Email       = "felipe@xxxxxxx.com.br"; //Replace with recipient email address
    $subject        = 'Orçamento do site'; //Subject line for emails


    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        //exit script outputting json data
        $output = json_encode(
        array(
            'type'=>'error',
            'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
        ));

        die($output);
    }

    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userPhone"]) || !isset($_POST["userDate"]) || !isset($_POST["userQuant"]))
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Os campos de entrada estão vazios!  '));
        die($output);
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Phone =                  $_POST["userPhone"];
    $user_Date =                  $_POST["userDate"]; 
    $user_Config       = filter_var($_POST["userConfig"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Quant =                  $_POST["userQuant"];
    $user_Equip       = filter_var($_POST["userEquip"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    //$user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["userMessage"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_Name)<3) // If length is less than 3 it will throw an HTTP error.
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'O campo nome não pode ficar vazio'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Por favor ultilize um e-mail válido'));
        die($output);
    }

    if(strlen($user_Phone)<5) //check emtpy phone
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Por favor insira um número de telefone'));
        die($output);
    }


    if(strlen($user_Date)<5) //check emtpy date
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Por favor insira uma data para o evento'));
        die($output);
    }

     if(strlen($user_Quant)<2) //check emtpy date
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Por favor insira a quantidade de pessoas para o evento'));
        die($output);
    }


    $message_Body = "<strong>Name: </strong>". $user_Name ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Email: </strong>". $user_Email ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Phone: </strong>". $user_Phone ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Data do Evento: </strong>". $user_Date ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Quantidade de pessoas: </strong>". $user_Quant ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Configurações do evento: </strong>". $user_Config ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Equipamentos: </strong>". $user_Equip ."<br>";
    //$message_Body .= "<strong>Message: </strong>". $user_Message ."<br>";



    $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($user_Email) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($user_Email) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";



    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(). "\r\n" .
    'Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8';



    $sentMail = @mail($to_Email, $subject, $message_Body, $headers);

    if(!$sentMail)
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Ocorreu um erro tente novamente'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Olá '. $user_Name .' Obrigado pelo seu contato retornaremos em breve.'));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It helps when you post the relevant parts in your question.

Comment: @Akintunde I understand I've posted my complete code so you can see the structure of the form the question here is that I can not get the fields that are with select because I did not like calling those two fields in my php code and js know They have to be an array like I did for example in name = "config []" I know this is an array more how should I make it call from my php code and JS

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you call `filter_var` (expects string) on `$_POST["userConfig"]` and `$_POST["userEquip"]` which will be arrays because of the multi-select.

Maybe you should try [filter_var_array](http://php.net/manual/de/function.filter-var-array.php) instead.

Answer (score 1):

In your **HTML**, your select name should not take braces []:

```
<select id="select-picker" class="selectpicker config" multiple
        name="config" id="config" data-selected-text-format="count > 3" 
        title="Configurações do evento">
```

In your **javascript** fetch selected datas like this:

```
var user_config     = $('select[name=config]').val();
```

that will return only selected configs.

i hope that helps :)

Comment: Friend if I edit sky code the way you passed me when I submit my form and instead of appearing the values selected in the select picker appears a parallel written array

Just remembering that it is a select multiple u whether the user will be able to select more than one value